# Error in building rosberrypi_cam node in RPi with ROS Indigo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following this [link](https://github.com/japonophile/rosberrypi_cam) for installing ROS driver for raspberrypi camera module. But after executing the command
sudo ./src/catkin/bin/catkin_make_isolated --install --pkg rosberrypi_cam -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -Draspicam_DIR:PATH=/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/external_src/raspicam/build/ --install-space /opt/ros/indigo -j2
I am getting this error...

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/libraspicam.so', needed by '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosberrypi_cam/lib/rosberrypi_cam/rosberrypi_cam_node'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:707: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/rosberrypi_cam_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/rosberrypi_cam_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'rosberrypi_cam': 
  Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/build_isolated/rosberrypi_cam && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.
```

If anyone has faced the same issue in raspbian Jessie, please help. Thank you.

Do I need to install openCV2 for this ROS package, as the main.cpp files includes certain header files from opncv2, does that indicate that it require openCV in raspbian??????

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/272435/error-in-building-rosberrypi_cam-node-in-rpi-with-ros-indigo/) by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2017-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You need to install the package camera_info_manager in your workspace.

You can do it by following the directions at the end of the ROSberry tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi with rosinstall.

---

Originally posted by [Nico__](https://answers.ros.org/users/27606/nico__/) with karma: 36 on 2017-10-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-10-09**:
I tried to install the package camera_info_manager in the ros_catkin_ws using sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-camera-info-manager, but got an error
Unable to locate package...
Please help regarding installation of camera_info_manager.
I have followed the same page of instructions as suggested by you

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-10-09**:
I could successfully install camera_info_manager and camera_callibration_parsers,after installing them I am getting this error.
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/usr/local/lib/libraspicam.so', needed by '/home/pi/ros_catkin_ws/devel_isolated/rosberrypi_cam/lib/rosberrypi_cam/rosberrypi_cam_node'

**Comment by [user_123](https://answers.ros.org/users/28458/user_123/) on 2017-10-09**:
Please help with the above problem @Nico__

**Comment by [Nico__](https://answers.ros.org/users/27606/nico__/) on 2017-10-12**:
Did you follow every steps of https://github.com/japonophile/rosberrypi_cam that you mention on your original post?